# Can I proudly say "the way of my beloved prophet Muhammad SAW will not lead me to hell fire"

Tags: halal-haram, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, shafii

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I have come across may people that sometimes when am trying to do some daawah for them, they used to ask that do you think this is the way, and sometimes I feel to said that "with this way you will not enter hell fire" but am somehow confused if am allowed to say so
I hope you help me with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> لَّقَدْ كَانَ لَكُمْ فِى رَسُولِ ٱللَّهِ أُسْوَةٌ حَسَنَةٌ لِّمَن كَانَ يَرْجُوا۟ ٱللَّهَ وَٱلْيَوْمَ ٱلْـَٔاخِرَ وَذَكَرَ ٱللَّهَ
> كَثِيرًا
>
> 33:21
>
> **Indeed**, in the Messenger of Allah you have an excellent example for whoever has hope in Allah and the Last Day, and remembers Allah often.

Yes you must be clear in belief that "the way of beloved prophet Muhammad SAW will not lead you to hell fire". Confusion in this belief can be sign of week iman. Before going for dawah to others we should give dawah to ourself and strengthen faith. You should be super clear and there should not be a little confusion that the way of beloved prophet Muhammad SAW is the way and it is the only way.

Confusion in dawah can be dangerous, you can see cases people slipping in dawah when there own faith was not strong.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Downvoted

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I agree with the answer, I think I need to strengthen my faith more, thank you @XIMRX